# Post method (rest API) in ionic3 not working in Android device but works fine in ionic serve

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

```
**my homepage.ts file:**
```

my home.ts file to print the data fetching it into the post JSON data

```
  export class HomePage {
     public datasss: any;
      public data1: any;
      public locat: any;
       public datas: any;

      public postParams =
      {
        "latitude": 11.0168,
        "longitude": 76.9558,
        "location": "cbe"
      }
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private httpprovider: HttpProvider) {

        this.getmethod();
       // this.dologin();
      }

      dologin() {
        this.httpprovider.log(this.postParams).then((result) => {
          this.datas = result;
          console.log("this.datasss", this.datas);
          this.locat = this.datas.data.location;

        }, (err) => {

          console.log("errorrr",err);

        });
      }


      getmethod()
      {
        this.httpprovider.locationlist().then((result) => {
          this.data1 = result;

          this.datasss = this.data1.data;
          console.log("this.data1",this.data1);



        }, (err) => {
                  console.log("err",err);
        });
      }


    }
```

MyHttpprovider.ts file:

In Httpprovider file both get and post method data will be getting the remote json rest api.

```
export class HttpProvider {
  private url: string = "api/add-location";

  private url_locationlist: string ="api/location-list";

  headers: Headers;
  options: RequestOptions;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9'
    });
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
  }



  log(credentials) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res.json());
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }

  locationlist(): Promise<any>
  {
    return this.http
      .get(this.url_locationlist, this.options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);

}
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

**ionic.config.json file:**

```
   {
      "name": "httppost",
      "app_id": "",
      "type": "ionic-angular",
      "integrations": {
        "cordova": {}
      },
      "proxies": [
        {
          "path": "/api",
          "proxyUrl": "http://192.168.0.17/sso/public/api"
        }
      ]
    }
```

when i was build the apk in android and running in to device result will not be showing but ionic serve and console working fine.......
      Any answer thanks...!!!

Comment: do you get console logs when you run in device? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: yeah but it contain  error like failed to load  **http:/// android-assets/www/api/location-list**  resource: net:: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND                                        **err in Response**